# Plotly Dash reference lines are not showing up - python

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to build a bar chart with some reference lines.

```
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = px.bar(x=[20, 14, 23], y=animals, orientation='h')
fig.add_vline(x=10, y1=0.33)
fig.add_vline(x=15, y0=0.33, y1=0.66, line_dash="dot")
fig.show()
```

here is the result
[image]

But when I do exactly the same whiting the Dash app reference lines are disappearing. Result:
[image]

UPDATE:
Thanks to a question from @vestland I figured out that the reason was in a template I was using. Here is the code for the app:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px

import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates.default = "simple_white"

animals = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
fig = px.bar(x=[20, 14, 23], y=animals, orientation='h')
fig.add_vline(x=10, y0=0, y1=0.33,)
fig.add_vline(x=15, y0=0.33, y1=0.66, line_dash="dot")
chart_bar = dcc.Graph(figure=fig, config={'displaylogo': False})

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport",
                            "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([dbc.Col(html.Div(id='benchmark-chart', children=chart_bar), md=6),
             dbc.Col(html.Div(id='spider-chart'), md=6)],
            className='app-body',
            style={'margin-top': '20px'})
            ],
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

when comment out this part

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates.default = "simple_white"
```

the problem is gone, reference lines are back.

Did anyone encountered something like that? Why is this happening?
How to show reference lines with the template?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could share the code for your Dash app?

Comment: @vestland thanks for you question. I've updated the topic.